Is drunk driving an aveirah in the absence of secular laws against it and with no damages?
For the vast majority of the world, drunk driving (also known as drink driving, Driving Under the Influence (DUI), or Driving While Intoxicated (DWI)) is forbidden under dina d'malchuta dina since DUI is outlawed nearly everywhere.
When I look at history, however, I find that secular drunk driving laws are of rather recent vintage. For example, drunk driving laws in the USA seem to have come into existence only in the 20th century.
To that end, in the absence of secular drunk driving laws (e.g. essentially the entire world prior to 1900, some places even after that, or at least hypothetically, today), is drunk driving an aveirah? I know that causing harm can result in liability (e.g. someone who accidentally kills another while driving drunk may be liable to go to a City of Refuge), I am considering cases where only the risk of damage or harm happened, not actual damage or harm. That is, I'm asking about a case where:

A Jewish driver drives a motor vehicle while too intoxicated to do so safely, in a manner that could reasonably damage property or harm or kill another.
No harm as countenanced above actually happens, not because of intent but because of chance factors outside the control of the person. This means that no person was injured or killed, no livestock or other property was damaged, etc.
The act is not illegal under local law.

In other words, is driving drunk without harming anyone inherently an aveirah, or is an aveirah only because of dina d'malchuta dina and the fact that essentially every country nowadays outlaws DUI?

See Bava Kamma 46a with Tosafot ד"ה אלא (second answer) that it's possible to transgress the prohibition of ולא תשים דמים בביתך even by performing an act with no legal liability

Drunk driving is also dangerous to the driver him/herself

Driving itself only came into existance in the 20th century. Are you looking for Rishonim on vaping as well?

I was told by a rav that, a drunk driver has the din of a רוצח, mudrerer, and one must do anything in his power to stop him. E.g. pop the tires...

It's the same din as sleep-deprived pilots and nearsighted chainsaw operators.
